# How to cancel fetching in loaders react-router-dom v6.4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

react-router-dom 6.4 release introduced new loader feature like that

```
createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <Teams />,
    path: "teams",
    loader: async () => {
      return fakeDb.from("teams").select("*");
    },
    children: [
      {
        element: <Team />,
        path: ":teamId",
        loader: async ({ params }) => {
          return fetch(`/api/teams/${params.teamId}.json`);
        },
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

But here is the thing, is it somehow possible to cancel those requests on component unmount, how we did easily in useEffect return before?
I know that it accepts request object as params, and it has signal inside. But how to cancel this signal, I don't get it

```
function loader({ request }) {
  return fetch("/api/teams.json", {
    signal: request.signal,
  });
```

}

Comment: No, not really. IIRC the route loader function is called prior to that route's `element` being mounted and rendered. What exactly is the issue or problem you are seeing with your code?

Comment: The problem that my loaders can be really heavy, and imagine I need to wait 3 second to load data before I go to the page. What I want, that if I navigate to another page during those 3 seconds, all my requests from loader are cancelled and I'm no more waiting for them.

Comment: @DrewReese, but actually now I know that react does it automatically, if I pass signal to fetch. That's all what you need to do, literally

Comment: Ah, yeah, makes sense. I don't think the docs explicitly call this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a controller in a loader, then abort it in component with useEffect hook cleanup function.
I did this with Axios for example:

```
export const testComponentLoader = async ({ request, params }) => {
    const controller = new AbortController()
    axios_instance.defaults.signal = controller.signal
    
    return defer({
        /* Return controller to component */
        controller: controller,
        /* Requests here, one or many */ 
        requestOne: axios_instance.get('url_one'),
        requestTwo: axios_instance.get('url_two'),
    })

const TestComponent = () => {
    const data = useLoaderData()
    const { controller } = data

    useEffect(() => {
        /* Abort controller when component unmount */
        /* i.e. user does not want to wait and changed route   */
        return () => controller.abort()
    }, [])
    
    return (
         {/* Your template with Suspence and Await */}
    )
}

export default TestComponent
```

Comment: There is no need to use useEffect at all. You just need to pass signal from sedond params of object, and react router will do the rest, it will automatically abort your request on unmount.

Comment: Unfortunately, passing { signal: request.signal } to Axios instance does not abort request.